# Cross-region database access how to avoid higher timeouts

Tags: amazon-web-services

My database is in one AWS region.

I am going to deploy the code now.

Wants to know if I deploy code in another region(which will be preferable in my case) whether cross-region access of database resources will lead to higher timeouts?

If yes how to handle this scenario.

Comment: you can look into replicas, but this depends on specific database you're using.

Comment: It is recommended that your application is **as close as possible** to your database to reduce latency. High latency will result in slow response times and potentially more connection issues. The best would be to have them both in the same AZ, or at least the same region.